# Upgrade SSIS packages to SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to upgrade my SSIS packages from sql server 2012 to 2019. I changed Target Server Version to 2014 and 2016 and the solution runs fine. After Deploy I get "The binary code for the script is not found."
When I change Target Server Version to 2017 I get an error in my scripts as : "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute is not defined."

What am I missing?

Comment: if they're for 2019, why didn't you choose 2019 as the target version?

Comment: @Larnu I tried change to 2019 in first place but it didn't work. Then I tried "slowly" first to 2014, 2016, etc

Comment: *"it didn't work"* that doesn't tell us a lot. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: That's the nature of the beast. You need to open Script Tasks/Script Components manually and run Build, checking that build is successful in the Output pane.

Comment: Change to 2017 or 2019 I get the same error: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute is not defined.". I also get some warnings. I attached my logs: https://imgur.com/a/J4tDG32

Comment: (1) Are you using VS2019? (2) Go to the Script Task/Component properties. Select **Build** tab. **Platform target:** allows to change to one of: Any CPU, x86, or x64.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks but I still got the same errors

Comment: (1) Are you using VS2019?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Yes, I'm using VS 2019.

Comment: Please check if it is (1) VS2019 v.16.11.1, and (2) SQL Server Integration Services Projects extension v.3.15 Some earlier VS2019 builds and extension had problems with Script Tasks.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Yes VS 2019 v16.11.1 and SQl Server integration v3.15. Any idea how to workaround?

Comment: I would suggest to create a brand new SSIS package, add a Script Task. Build it, and run successfully. After that carbon copy its (1) settings, and (2) references to the existing migrated SSIS packages.